# Angular: how to add a unique .htaccess file per configuration?

Tags: angular, .htaccess, build, angular-cli, .htpasswd

My Angular app contains 2 build configurations: staging, and production.

---

Currently I have a standard `.htaccess` file for all builds, by including it in my assets:

```
"assets": [
  "src/.htaccess",
  "src/assets",
  "src/favicon.png"
],
```

---

I want to password protect my staging build directory with a `.htpasswd` file, so I updated my assets to include it:

```
"assets": [
  "src/.htaccess",
  "src/.htpasswd"
  "src/assets",
  "src/favicon.png"
],
```

The `htpasswd` file can be included in every build, because without a mention in the `.htaccess` file, it does nothing.

---

Then, I've created a second `.htaccess` file, called `.htaccess.dev`, with the following added lines:

```
AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile /home/admin/domains/dev.***.com/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

This file with the extra lines should replace the `.htaccess` file in the staging build, so I added the following configuration to my `angular.json` file:

```
"build": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "staging": {
      ...
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/.htaccess",
          "with": "src/.htaccess.dev"
        },
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`fileReplacements` works fine for my `.env`, but **It does not replace my htaccess file**. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it seems that `fileReplacements` only works for `.ts` files.

---

[angular/devkit#885](https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/885):

> Currently, the file replacement functionality works only for TS files. More specifically - it works only for files that are part of the webpack compiler host.

This will (apparently) be fixed in Angular 6.1.

[See this GitHub thread for more info](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10881)

---

### Update 2018-08-28

This is now supported [(confirmed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054003/how-to-conditionally-import-different-files-during-build-in-angular-6) in Angular 6.1