# Is there a way to extend configurations in angular.json?

Tags: json, angular, angular-cli

While building my Angular 6 application, I need to specify 2 things at once:

- If it's production or development build
- The locale I'm using

In my `angular.json` I have:

```
"build": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true
    },
    "pl": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/assets/i18n/translations.json",
          "with": "src/assets/i18n/pl.json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "en": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/assets/i18n/translations.json",
          "with": "src/assets/i18n/en.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But when I'm doing `ng build --configuration=en --configuration=production` I'm getting an error `Configuration 'en,production' could not be found`. I understand it means you can specify only 1 configuration at a time.

This means I need to create separate `en`, `pl`, `productionEn`, `productionPl` configurations. Though not the cleanest pattern, I can live with that.

```
"build": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true
    },
    "pl": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/assets/i18n/translations.json",
          "with": "src/assets/i18n/pl.json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "en": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/assets/i18n/translations.json",
          "with": "src/assets/i18n/en.json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "productionPl": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        },
        {
          "replace": "src/assets/i18n/translations.json",
          "with": "src/assets/i18n/pl.json"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true
    },
    "productionEn": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        },
        {
          "replace": "src/assets/i18n/translations.json",
          "with": "src/assets/i18n/en.json"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true
    }
  }
}
```

But what I can't live with is copying and pasting the whole `production` configuration contents into `productionEn` and `productionPl`. If I add even more locales, or some third separate aspect that I'd like to specify during build, this pattern would become a total nightmare to maintain. Unfortunately it seem it's the pattern that Angular team recommends in their [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-aot-compiler).

Is there a way to tell Angular CLI that `productionEn` extends `production`, so to not duplicate the same configuration code multiple times? Something like the code below:

```
"build": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      (...)
    },
    "pl": {
      "extends": "production",
      (...)
    },
    "en": {
      "extends": "production",
      (...)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can't you simply omit the values equals? I think that you can only add the keys for "outputPath", "i18nFile","i18nFormat","i18nLocale" and "i18nMissingTranslation" but i'm not sure

Comment: @Eliseo I don't understand your point. As I can set only 1 configuration during the build, I need to specify all the values; don't see what I can omit.

Comment: Maybe you have got a spelling mistake? `Configuration 'en,productions' could not be found` but your configurations name is `production` without s.

Comment: @ngfelixl: Good catch, but unfortunately it was just a typo I must have made when editing the post. I tested it again and it doesn't work, producing the error with `en,production` not `en,productions`. I corrected the post.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There finally is a way to do it, specifying multiple configurations in the command line:

`ng build --configuration=en,production`

[Relevant issue in Angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/15819)

Note that `--prod` flag is ignored when you use `--configuration` (so you need to add `production` to the configuration list explicitly).

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/cli/build) for `--configuration=configuration`:

> A named build target, as specified in the "configurations" section of angular.json. Each named target is accompanied by a configuration of option defaults for that target. Setting this explicitly overrides the "--prod" flag
>
> Aliases: -c

Comment: Nice one! THX! :)

Comment: Do you know which version of angular this is available from ? I currently use angular core 8.2.14 and angular cli 8.3.20 and can’t get it working.

Comment: @ArchiFloyd Release history shows it available in [`9.0.0-next.10`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v9.0.0-next.10). I'm not sure what exactly `-next.10` means, but it seems it'll be available only in `9.0.0`.

Comment: I wonder how this work with say: `ng serve --configuration=en,myenv` It says: `Configuration 'en,myenv' is not set in the workspace.`

Comment: @Agoun: Are you sure you're using the version in which it's supported? Sounds to me like you're still using an old one, where the syntax isn't supported, and so comma is interpreted as part of the configuration name.

Comment: @RobertKusznier: this is probably the case, haven't upgraded yet (steps to be taken need extra attention and code updates for i18n support). Thank you Robert!

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work correctly with `serve`. I found I had to do it with browser-target instead, like `ng serve myapp --browser-target=myapp:build:local,en-US` or `ng serve myapp --browser-target=myapp:build:local,es-MX`. This would use both my "local" configuration and the right culture's config together. See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17473#issuecomment-641078028).

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** see accepted answer for building with multiple configurations. The details below are now outdated

---

Reading through some issues and `angular.json` documentation, it appears that the `options` act as the defaults for the project

```
"architect": {
        "build": {          
          "options": {...}
```

These are overridden with `partial` options set in the `configurations`. From the [Angular CLI workspace wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace):

```
configurations (object): A map of alternative target options.
configurationName (object): Partial options override for this builder.
```

This [issue comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11120#issuecomment-394968774) also mentions using `configurations` as an override

This sounds like all of the defaults for the project can be added to the `options` object e.g. move any duplicates from `production`, `productionPl` to the `options: {}`, and then add the `fileReplacements`, and the few other overrides that you require

Note: I have not tested this yet, it's just a suggestion based on the docs and issues

Comment: That's a lot of info I didn't get from the documentation, thanks! For a moment I thought it'd solve this issue, but I realized one problem. Moving common options from `build.configurations.production` into `build.options` would mean that every single `ng build` would be a production build. That's undesired, as `ng build` is also invoked for example by `ng serve` (it's defined in `serve.browserTarget` option in `angular.json`) and those builds need not do all the processing that production builds do. So `production` mode definitely needs to be switchable on and off and not the default one.

Comment: @RobertKusznier There are a lot of options that are identical between all those configurations, so you could move these up to the defaults couldn't you? That's all an `extends` feature would do in any case

Comment: But if I move them to `options`, they would be also applied when running development server (as it's also running `ng build`, just without `--prod`/`--configuration=production`). That's completely undesired. Do you know how to handle/fix that?

Comment: Note that these identical  options that you mention should be applied only for production builds.

Comment: @RobertKusznier From what I can see, apart from adding values to the default options, and overriding them in the configurations, there are no further CLI only solutions. Really what your looking for is an `extends`, which is a feature request (but I imagine that's way down the line: see `priority 3 nice to have` https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10612 )

Comment: So it's a feature request! Reading those issues I'm now convinced that what I ask for is simply impossible to achieve so far. Thanks for providing all those useful resources :).

Answer (score 5):

#### But this doesn't work for `ng serve` you say?

###### Here's what probably happened:

First, here's my configuration for `angular12/architect/build/configurations`:

```
"development": {

    "customWebpackConfig": {
       "path": "custom-webpack.dev.config.js",
       "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
    },

    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "optimization": false,
    "vendorChunk": true,
    "extractLicenses": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "namedChunks": true,
    "aot": true
},

"quick": {

    "fileReplacements": [
        {
            "replace": "src/app/app-routing.module.ts",
            "with": "src/app/app-routing.module.quick.ts"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a standard development config, with an added configuration called `quick` which is what I want to set in addition to the options from `development`.

(So my `quick` is the same as OP's `en` and `pl`.)

Sorry this isn't a magic new 'quick Angular build' feature (!) - I simply made a copy of my `app-routing` file, commented out every lazy module except the one I'm currently working with and configured the `fileReplacements` option to override the standard file. The build is significant faster for a large project. Clearly though I didn't want to accidentally deploy this which is why I needed a separate configuration.

What happens when you run `ng serve --configuration development,quick` is it looks in the **serve** part of the configuration (below). As you can see I added `quick` here as a browser target, referencing what I have above.

```
"serve": 
{
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",

    "options": {
       "browserTarget": "angular12:build"
    },

    "configurations": 
    {
       "production": {
          "browserTarget": "angular12:build:production"
       },
       "development": {
          "browserTarget": "angular12:build:development"
       },
       "quick": {
          "browserTarget": "angular12:build:quick"
       }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},
```

What's actually happening when you ask for `--configuration development,quick` is it merges these two nodes:

```
"development": {
   "browserTarget": "angular12:build:development"
}

"quick": {
   "browserTarget": "angular12:build:quick"
}
```

Which results in:

```
"development": {
   "browserTarget": "angular12:build:development"
}
```

Makes sense why it *didn't work* now :-)

#### Solution:

The solution is fortunately as simple as updating `serve/quick` to:

```
"quick": {
     "browserTarget": "angular12:build:development,quick"
}
```

Then simply run:

`ng-serve --configuration quick`

This will in turn will merge your `development` and `quick` configurations under `architect/build` as if you were running `ng build`.

---

PS. You may see I'm using `customWebpackConfig`. That is the [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) package that allows for customization. It's irrelevant to my answer, but allowed me to prove to myself that it was indeed working as I was able to observe both my customWebpack plugins running and only the single lazy chunk I wanted was built.

Comment: There's another way which I found after I discovered this. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17473. You can directly use `browser-target` like this: `ng serve --browser-target angular12:build:development,quick`. It's effectively doing the same thing, but I prefer my way. It's quicker ;-)

Answer (score -3):

are you ask about ?

```
"scripts": {
    [...]
    "build-i18n": "for lang in en es fr pt; 
       do ng build --config=$lang;
       done"
 }
```

Comment: It's not my question how to build all languages at once. Rather than that I'm asking how to build a specific language, let's say `en`, with `production` configuration? Something like `ng build --configuration=en --configuration=production`, but that doesn't work.